# Simplify $\det{A} = \left| \begin{array}{ccc} 1+a & 1+a^2 & 1+a^3\\ 1+b & 1+b^2 & 1+b^3\\ 1+c & 1+c^2 & 1+c^3 \end{array} \right|$

Tags: matrices, determinant

Simplify $\det{A} = \left| \begin{array}{}
1+a & 1+a^2 & 1+a^3\\
1+b & 1+b^2 & 1+b^3\\
1+c & 1+c^2 & 1+c^3
\end{array} \right|$.
I know that there're $(a-b)$, $(b-c)$, $(c-a)$ factors, but I want to find the best way to simplify it so I can apply for bigger determinants:

$\left| \begin{array}{}
1+a & 1+a^2 & 1+a^3 & 1+a^4\\
1+b & 1+b^2 & 1+b^3 & 1+b^4\\
1+c & 1+c^2 & 1+c^3 & 1+c^4\\
1+d & 1+d^2 & 1+d^3 & 1+d^4
\end{array} \right|$.

Could you give me a hint?
Thank you.

Comment: Determinant is invariant under elementary row and column operations. That means you can do $R_{1}=R_{1}-R_{2},R_{2}=R_{2}-R_{3},R_{3}=R_{3}-R_{4}$. Then check if somethings can be taken out as common factors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that by Cauchy
$$
\det(B+xy^T) = \det(A) + y^T(\operatorname{adj}B)x.
$$
Now, let
$$
B = \begin{pmatrix}
x_1& x_1^2 &\cdots & x_1^n\\
\vdots &\vdots& & \vdots\\
x_n& x_n^2 &\cdots & x_n^n\\
\end{pmatrix},
$$
then your matrix is $A = B + \mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T$. Thus
$$
\det A = \det(B + \mathbf{1}\mathbf{1}^T)=-\det\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & \mathbf{1}^T\\
\mathbf{1}& B
\end{pmatrix} = -\det\begin{pmatrix}
1-2 & \mathbf{1}^T\\
\mathbf{1}& B
\end{pmatrix} = -\det(V -2e_1e_1^T)=\\-\det V+2e_1^T(\operatorname{adj}V)e_1=2\det B-\det V,
$$
where $V = \begin{pmatrix}1&\mathbf{1}^T\\\mathbf{1}&B\end{pmatrix}$ is an $(n+1)\times(n+1)$Vandermonde matrix.

To simplify further, note that
$$
\det V = \det B\prod_{k=1}^n(x_k-1)/x_k,
$$
so then
$$
\det A = \det B\left(2 - \prod_{k=1}^n(x_k-1)/x_k\right).
$$

Answer (score 0):

It is also straightforward to compute the determinant explicitly and factorize the polynomial. For the first matrix $A=A(a,b,c)$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
\det(A) & = (abc + ab + ac - a + bc - b - c + 1)\\
 & \quad \cdot (a - b)(a - c)(b - c),
\end{align*}
and for the matrix $A=A(a,b,c,d)$ we obtain
\begin{align*}
\det(A) & = (abcd + abc + abd - ab + acd - ac - ad + a + bcd - bc - bd + b - cd + c + d -1) \\
 & \quad \cdot(a - b)(a - c)(a - d)(b - c)(b - d)(c - d)
\end{align*}
Clearly the last factors part is the Vandermonde determinant.